# Aggregate Summaries of Posts of Different Blogs in Multisite Instance

Tags: plugins, multisite, excerpt

I have a Multisite Wordpress installation with 7 different blogs. I want to show an aggregate of the summaries of posts from those 7 blogs in the main blog. Do you know a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of plugins, depending what you wanted.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-sitewide-tags/ 
Despite the name, it pulls in all posts to the main blog or a blog called 'tags'.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/diamond-multisite-widgets/
Give a list of the latest posts network-wide, all in a handy widget.